# Algorithm Analysis: Big O/Worst Case

Tags: algorithm

A homework question asks me to analyse the following code fragement:

```
for (int i = N; i > 0; i--)
    for (int j = 0; j < i; j++)
```

I think the inner loop runs the following number of times:

```
N + (N-1) + (N-2) + ... + (N - N + 1)
```

However, I'm having trouble converting that into O() notation.

Could someone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By observation, the inner loop runs 1 + 2 + ... + N times. That's exactly N(N+1)/2 (which is the formula for triangular numbers). First, remember the definition of big-O: it's that f is O(g) if |f/g| is bounded for large enough N. So for example this is O(exp(n)) and it's also O(n^3). It's also O(N(N+1)/2), but your teacher is probably expecting the answer O(N^2). How does one show that this is O(N^2)? Well (N(N+1)/2) / N^2 is 1/2 + 1/2N. This is bounded by 1 for N > 0.